# how can we access mobile device camera and mic with html page

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

one question, can we make HTML page and open in mobile device and add some code in HTML page to access mobile camera and mic device, it's this possible??

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible. you can do it with html5.

If you wanted to let users take a snapshot of themselves with the webcam, that's possible with `capture=camera:`

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

Recording a video or audio is similar:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder">
<input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone">
```

Read this article [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)